# doctrine2 results depending on previous query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a strange issue with doctrine2 queries.

My UniteRepository have 2 methods : findA and findB (each are similar with several left join)
Each method return the result i expect.

But if i call findA then findB, the findB return false results !
Thus, the following code is wrong, but good if i comment the first line :

```
    $a =  $this->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Unite')->findA();
    $b =  $this->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Unite')->findB();

    foreach ($b as $unite) {
        foreach ($unite->getEvaluations() as $evaluation) {
            echo $evaluation->getId();
        }
    }
```

The findA and findB methods :

```
public function findA() {
      $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
       ->select('u, fr, eus, pus, r, pvus, sg, sf, sm')       
       ->leftJoin('u.Evaluations','eus')   
         ->leftJoin('eus.FicheRisque','fr')                
         ->leftJoin('eus.Preconisations','pus')
         ->leftJoin('eus.Preventions','pvus')     
         ->leftJoin('eus.Reponses','r')
            ->leftJoin('r.SituationGravite','sg')
            ->leftJoin('r.SituationFrequence','sf')  
            ->leftJoin('r.SituationMaitrise','sm')    
       ->where('fr.actif = true and fr.isRPS = false and eus.resultat=1')
       ->orderby('fr.ordre');
       return $q->getQuery()->getResult();                             
  }       

 public function findB() {
      $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
       ->select('u, fr, eus, pus, r, pvus')       
       ->leftJoin('u.Evaluations','eus')       
         ->leftJoin('eus.FicheRisque','fr')                
         ->leftJoin('eus.Preconisations','pus')
         ->leftJoin('eus.Preventions','pvus')     
         ->leftJoin('eus.Reponses','r')     
       ->where('fr.actif = true and fr.isRPS = true')
       ->orderby('fr.ordre');          
       return $q->getQuery()->getResult();                             
  }
```

Comment: `->where(fr.actif = true and fr.isRPS = false and eus.resultat=1)` is this a typo ? it seems quotes between `(..)` are missing.

Comment: yes it's a typo, i have edited my question

Comment: What about having `$uniteRepository = $this->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Unite')` then simply `$a = $uniteRepository->findA()` and same for B. I don't think this will change much but since this behavior is kind of weird !

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer ...
Doctrine use Identity Map pattern (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html#how-doctrine-keeps-track-of-objects)

So in order to improve performance Doctrine put the result in cache.

to solve this issue, http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map gave me this (simple) answer :

```
$em->clear();
```